# Complex `where` dramatically affects query performance

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance, explain, where

There are much more complex queries running on these tables that are much faster but this one takes 90+ seconds to run.

What am I doing wrong here? How can this be improved?

```sql
SELECT 
            r.id as `ID`,  
            concat(r.fname, " ", r.lname) as `Applicant`,
            r.added `App Time`,
            concat(trim(r.city), ", ", r.state) as `City`, 
            coalesce(q.count, 0) as `Attempts`,
            coalesce(q.last_called, 0) as `Last Called`,
            null as `Removed`
        FROM myfreshp_crm.records r 
        left join (
            SELECT rid, count(rid) as count, max(called) as last_called
            from myfreshp_crm.cc_queue
            where status = 'called'
            group by rid
        ) q on q.rid = r.id 
        left join (
            select rid, max(time) as appt
            from myfreshp_crm.calendar 
            where event = 'Appointment' 
            group by rid
        ) a on a.rid = r.id
        left join (
            select rid, max(sent) as sent
            from myfreshp_crm.cc_queue
            group by rid
        ) c on c.rid = r.id
        where 
        r.id not in (select lead_id from asap_blacklist) 
        and coalesce(q.count, 0) < 4
        AND ( 
            c.sent > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 28)) OR
            r.added > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (60 * 60 * 24 * 28))
        )
        AND (
            (
                a.appt is not null
                and a.appt < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
                and c.sent is not null
                and c.sent > a.appt
            ) OR (
                r.source = 'Online' 
                and a.appt is null
            )
        )
```

`Explain extended..` is as follows:

```
+----+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table          | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref               | rows    | filtered | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | r              | ALL  | added,source  | NULL        | NULL    | NULL              | 3436521 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>     | ref  | <auto_key0>   | <auto_key0> | 4       | myfreshp_crm.r.id |      10 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3>     | ref  | <auto_key1>   | <auto_key1> | 4       | myfreshp_crm.r.id |      15 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived4>     | ref  | <auto_key1>   | <auto_key1> | 4       | myfreshp_crm.r.id |      15 |   100.00 | Using where                                  |
|  5 | SUBQUERY    | asap_blacklist | ALL  | NULL          | NULL        | NULL    | NULL              |     287 |   100.00 | NULL                                         |
|  4 | DERIVED     | cc_queue       | ALL  | rid           | NULL        | NULL    | NULL              |   77090 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
|  3 | DERIVED     | calendar       | ALL  | rid,event     | NULL        | NULL    | NULL              |  102750 |    97.15 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | cc_queue       | ALL  | rid,status    | NULL        | NULL    | NULL              |   77090 |    99.39 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set, 1 warning (0.08 sec)
```

`Show warnings;` provides this:

```
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select `myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`id` AS `ID`,concat(`myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`fname`,' ',`myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`lname`) AS `Applicant`,`myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`added` AS `App Time`,concat(trim(`myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`city`),', ',`myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`state`) AS `City`,coalesce(`q`.`count`,0) AS `Attempts`,coalesce(`q`.`last_called`,0) AS `Last Called`,NULL AS `Removed` from `myfreshp_crm`.`records` `r` left join (/* select#2 */ select `myfreshp_crm`.`cc_queue`.`rid` AS `rid`,count(`myfreshp_crm`.`cc_queue`.`rid`) AS `count`,max(`myfreshp_crm`.`cc_queue`.`called`) AS `last_called` from `myfreshp_crm`.`cc_queue` where (`myfreshp_crm`.`cc_queue`.`status` = 'called') group by `myfreshp_crm`.`cc_queue`.`rid`) `q` on((`q`.`rid` = `myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`id`)) left join (/* select#3 */ select `myfreshp_crm`.`calendar`.`rid` AS `rid`,max(`myfreshp_crm`.`calendar`.`time`) AS `appt` from `myfreshp_crm`.`calendar` where (`myfreshp_crm`.`calendar`.`event` = 'Appointment') group by `myfreshp_crm`.`calendar`.`rid`) `a` on((`a`.`rid` = `myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`id`)) left join (/* select#4 */ select `myfreshp_crm`.`cc_queue`.`rid` AS `rid`,max(`myfreshp_crm`.`cc_queue`.`sent`) AS `sent` from `myfreshp_crm`.`cc_queue` group by `myfreshp_crm`.`cc_queue`.`rid`) `c` on((`c`.`rid` = `myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`id`)) where ((not(<in_optimizer>(`myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`id`,`myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`id` in ( <materialize> (/* select#5 */ select `myfreshp_crm`.`asap_blacklist`.`lead_id` from `myfreshp_crm`.`asap_blacklist` where 1 ), <primary_index_lookup>(`myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`id` in <temporary table> on <auto_key> where ((`myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`id` = `materialized-subquery`.`lead_id`))))))) and (coalesce(`q`.`count`,0) < 4) and ((`c`.`sent` > <cache>((unix_timestamp() - (((60 * 60) * 24) * 28)))) or (`myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`added` > <cache>((unix_timestamp() - (((60 * 60) * 24) * 28))))) and (((`a`.`appt` is not null) and (`a`.`appt` < <cache>(unix_timestamp())) and (`c`.`sent` is not null) and (`c`.`sent` > `a`.`appt`)) or ((`myfreshp_crm`.`r`.`source` = 'Online') and isnull(`a`.`appt`)))) |
+-------+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The `records` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `records` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `cid` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `vid` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `added` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `zip` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `phone1` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `phone2` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `mobilephone` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive','followup','responded','sold','dead') NOT NULL,
  `ssn` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `perm` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `printed_label` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `printed_letter` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `dob` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'imported',
  `opt_out` enum('no','yes') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
  `other_data` longtext NOT NULL,
  `sms_opt_in` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `cid` (`cid`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `vid` (`vid`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `uid_2` (`uid`),
  KEY `printed_label` (`printed_label`),
  KEY `fname` (`fname`),
  KEY `mname` (`mname`),
  KEY `lname` (`lname`),
  KEY `phone1` (`phone1`),
  KEY `phone2` (`phone2`),
  KEY `printed_letter` (`printed_letter`),
  KEY `address` (`address`),
  KEY `city` (`city`),
  KEY `state` (`state`),
  KEY `added` (`added`),
  KEY `source` (`source`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `zip` (`zip`),
  KEY `ssn` (`ssn`),
  KEY `dob` (`dob`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8938455 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The `cc_queue` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `cc_queue` (
  `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rid` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `sent` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `called` int(30) NOT NULL,
  `reason` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('waiting','called') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `disposition` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sentToCC` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `rid` (`rid`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `sent` (`sent`),
  KEY `called` (`called`),
  KEY `sentToCC` (`sentToCC`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=77097 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

The `calendar` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `calendar` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rid` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `added` int(25) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `event` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `details` varchar(1000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`),
  KEY `rid` (`rid`),
  KEY `added` (`added`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `event` (`event`(333))
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=151930 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

The `asap_blacklist` table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `asap_blacklist` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lead_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1483 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

And here's what `information_schema` says...

```
select * from information_schema.tables where table_name in ('records', 'cc_queue', 'calendar', 'asap_blacklist');
+---------------+--------------+----------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------------+
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME     | TABLE_TYPE | ENGINE | VERSION | ROW_FORMAT | TABLE_ROWS | AVG_ROW_LENGTH | DATA_LENGTH | MAX_DATA_LENGTH | INDEX_LENGTH | DATA_FREE | AUTO_INCREMENT | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         | CHECK_TIME          | TABLE_COLLATION   | CHECKSUM | CREATE_OPTIONS | TABLE_COMMENT |
+---------------+--------------+----------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------------+
| def           | myfreshp_crm | asap_blacklist | BASE TABLE | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |        287 |             57 |       16384 |               0 |            0 |         0 |           1483 | 2021-03-13 22:20:35 | NULL                | NULL                | utf8_bin          |     NULL |                |               |
| def           | myfreshp_crm | calendar       | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |     102750 |            178 |    18325956 | 281474976710655 |      7480320 |         0 |         151930 | 2015-10-06 13:07:55 | 2021-05-04 21:38:09 | 2016-06-04 21:10:52 | utf8_unicode_ci   |     NULL |                |               |
| def           | myfreshp_crm | cc_queue       | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |      77092 |            112 |    14584528 | 281474976710655 |      5064704 |   5935072 |          77097 | 2015-12-09 09:43:24 | 2021-05-05 09:30:02 | 2016-06-04 21:10:52 | utf8_unicode_ci   |     NULL |                |               |
| def           | myfreshp_crm | records        | BASE TABLE | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    |    3436523 |            204 |   702349312 |               0 |   1715929088 |   6291456 |        8938456 | 2021-02-18 04:16:51 | NULL                | NULL                | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |               |
+---------------+--------------+----------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: [Duplicate on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67402909). Please do not cross-post here. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things that jump out immediately with the `information_schema` Details:

- **MyISAM**
- differing collations

**Regarding MyISAM**

When there is a `JOIN` between MyISAM and InnoDB, the InnoDB tables will suffer from table-level lock behavior instead of row-level locking because of how MyISAM needs to operate.

The query engine in MySQL relies a great deal on index cardinality to determine an optimized plan. Index cardinality is generally stable in MyISAM tables so long as the data is static … which is rarely ever the case. InnoDB index cardinality is different from one minute to the next.

For the reasons above, I would *strongly* advise converting any MyISAM tables to InnoDB during your next database maintenance window.

**Regarding the different collations**

The query engine needs to convert `utf8_bin`, `utf8_unicode_ci`, and `latin1_swedish_ci` to something that is consistent with every query, and some of the indexes on your tables are quite large. This takes time. Ideally every table in the database has the same collation to avoid these expensive conversions.

**Additional Reading**

[Here’s a bug report that’s been open for over a decade](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=57118) regarding MySQL’s performance when joining MyISAM and InnoDB tables for queries. It’s even worse when the result of the query is then used to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` a MyISAM table. Locking everywhere!

Answer (score 1):

These are likely to help with performance (but I can't tell by how much):

```
cc_queue:  INDEX(status, rid, called)  -- (and toss INDEX(status))
calendar:  INDEX(event, rid, time)     -- see below
cc_queue:  INDEX(rid, sent)            -- (and toss INDEX(rid))
```

`INDEX(event(333))` is rarely useful.  If you have 5.7 or later, that "index prefix" is not necessary.

`OR` is a performance killer.